# Same classes with different template argument cannot access private fields of each other

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a template class `my_class<T>` which is receiving a constructor argument `my_class<U>` (generally with different template parameter).
Unlike the code without templates, or with the same template parameter, I cannot access `my_class<U>` instance private fields, nevertheless it's the same class.

```
template <class T>
class my_class {

    private:            
       T * data;

    public: 
        template <class U>
        my_class(const my_class<U> & p) {
            data = p.data; // <-- visibility exposing
        }
}
```

Is there a trick to make it possible? Maybe I can define a friend class with a different template argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment: "It should works only if U is a child of T. Is there any way to make this?".. Use traits.. That will help you determine if U derived from T..

With the below traits, the following are the allowed arguments to functions that use them:

```
/**
    Arguments can be (is_non_class_same<T, U>::value):
        T = T     -> U = T for any class.
        T = void* -> U = any non-class pointer.
        T = int*  -> U = int*. U cannot be a float*. Incompatible pointers.
        T = int   -> U = float
        T = double -> U = float or int.  Valid.. double is large enough to hold float and int.
        T = int   -> U = double  Invalid.. double is larger than type float.. loss of precision.
        T = float -> U = double  Invalid.. double is larger than type float.. loss of precision.

    Arguments can be (is_class_same<T, U>::value, U>::type):

        T = Base* -> U = Base*.
        T = Base* -> U = Derived*
        T = Base  -> U = Derived  Invalid.. See: Slicing Problem.
**/
```

---

Example (working code):   http://ideone.com/dHZhHc  <-- live example..

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_non_class_same : public std::integral_constant<bool, (!std::is_base_of<
        typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type,
        typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type>::value &&
        std::is_convertible<U, T>::value && sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U)) ||
(std::is_class<T>::value && std::is_class<U>::value &&
 !std::is_pointer<T>::value && !std::is_pointer<U>::value &&
 std::is_same<T, U>::value)>
{};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_class_same : public std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_base_of<
        typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type,
        typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type>::value &&
        std::is_pointer<T>::value>
{};


class Node
{
protected:
    Node* previous;
    Node* next;

    Node() : previous(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}

    template<class T, class TD>
    friend class linked_ptr;

public:
    virtual ~Node() {}

};

template<typename T, typename TD = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>
class linked_ptr : public Node
{
private:
    template<class, class> friend class linked_ptr; /** Access friend level **/
    T data;

public:

    template<class U, typename TU = typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_non_class_same<T, U>::value || is_class_same<T, U>::value, U>::type>
    linked_ptr(U data) : data(data) {}
    ~linked_ptr();

    template<class U, typename TU = typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_non_class_same<T, U>::value || is_class_same<T, U>::value, U>::type>
    void setData(U data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }

    template<class U, typename TU = typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_non_class_same<T, U>::value || is_class_same<T, U>::value, U>::type>
    void append(U data);
};

template<typename T, typename TD>
linked_ptr<T, TD>::~linked_ptr()
{
    TD(data);
    delete this->next;
}

template<typename T, typename TD>
template<typename U, typename TU, class>
void linked_ptr<T, TD>::append(U data)
{
    if (!this->next)
    {
        this->next = new linked_ptr<U>(data);
        this->next->previous = this;
        return;
    }

    Node* t = this->next;
    while(t->next != nullptr)
    {
        t = t->next;
    }

    t->next = new linked_ptr<U>(data);
}




class foo
{
public:
    virtual ~foo()
    {
        std::cout<<"destroyed foo\n";
    };

    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"foo\n";
    }
};

class bar : public foo
{
public:
    virtual ~bar()
    {
        std::cout<<"destroyed bar\n";
    }

    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"bar\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    linked_ptr<foo*> list(new foo());
    list.append(new bar());
    list.append(new bar());
    list.append(new foo());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make all different kinds of `linked_ptr<>` friends of each other by using the following declaration within the template class body of `linked_ptr<>`:

```
template <class> friend class linked_ptr;
```

However, doing so, you face the problem that you are attempting to assign to incompatible pointers. That is, if `U` is a different type from `T`, then `linked_ptr<U> *` will be a different type from `linked_ptr<T> *`, and more obviously, `U *` will be different from `T *`.

```
    data = p.data;            // error: assigning U* to T*
    next = p.next;            // error: assigning linked_ptr<U>* to linked_ptr<T>*
    ...
```

The C++ syntax allows you to use the unadorned `linked_ptr` within the class, but it is really an alias for the full template type (with the template parameters filled in).

Comment: It should works only if U is a child of T.
Is there any way to make this?